# OpenFile API returns error while opening file having name length above 127 characters

Tags: winapi, file-io

I am trying to open file which reside in a directory.
It is always return error code 13 if length is above or equal 127.

```
char name[200]="E:\\suri_temp\\abc85\\tool\\src1111\\turi_temp\\abc85\\tool\\src1111\\puri_temp\\abc85\\tool\\src\\nuri_temp\\abc85\\to\\abcd.tmp\\suri1111.log";

int len = strlen(name); //len=127

HFILE handle ;
WORD temp;
OFSTRUCT ofstruct;

if( (handle = OpenFile(name, &ofstruct, OF_EXIST))  ==  HFILE_ERROR )
{
    temp = GetLastError(); // if length 127 or above(it comes here temp = 13)
}
else
_lclose(handle); // if length is below 127 it comes here
```

Anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You are just finding out the hard way what's well documented in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365430%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for OpenFile:

> Note  This function has limited capabilities and is not recommended. For new application development, use the CreateFile function.
>
> The OFSTRUCT structure contains a path string member with a length that is limited to OFS_MAXPATHNAME characters, which is 128 characters. Because of this, you cannot use the OpenFile function to open a file with a path length that exceeds 128 characters. The CreateFile function does not have this path length limitation.

As indicated, use CreateFile() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
OpenFile(name, &ofstruct, OF_EXIST))
```

is ok in debug mode, but fails in release mode.
Use

```
if(GetFileAttributes("filename") == -1)
```